# Error loading development chrome extension: Invalid port or URL pattern is malformed

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load my development chrome extension to debug and I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Empty path.
```

Could not load manifest

This is how my manifest looks like:

```
    {
  "name": "My ext name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "....!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://localhost:*/admin",
        "https://myapp.mysite.com.br"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "estilera.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Match Patterns: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

As the error says, it's not able to find a path on the first match (`"*://localhost:*/admin",`).

This message is quite unclear but it means that you need to add a `/` on the final of your URLs to create a valid path. The interpreter doesn't automatically ads a `/` on the final.

So you would need to have something like:

```
  "content_scripts": [
     {
      "matches": [
        "*://localhost:*/admin/",
        "https://myapp.mysite.com.br/"
      ],
     }
   ]
```

**Bonus:** If you use cookies permission, you also have to follow this. In the opposite case, you'd have the error: `Permission '*://myapp.mysite.com.br' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.`

You also should add a `/`:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "*://localhost:*/admin/",
     "*://myapp.mysite.com.br/"
  ]
```

**Attention:** Sometimes when you get errors, the page doesn't show the refresh icon and isn't able to activate your extension anymore without any feedback. In this case, you must delete your extension and load it again!

Comment: 50% wrong, `/admin` is already a perfectly valid path so the problem is caused only by the second match pattern.